# Weak and weak-* convergence in $(\ell ^p)^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Study weak and weak-* convergence of $\{f_n\}_{n=1} ^{\infty}$ $\subset (\ell ^p)^*$ , $f_n(x_1,x_2,...) = x_n$ , $1<p<\infty$

I could prove that $\{f_n\}_{n=1} ^{\infty}$ does not converge in norm, but i don't know how to work with weak and weak-* convergence.
I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the dual of $\ell^p$?

Comment: The dual of $\ell ^p$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell ^q$

Comment: Indeed. So you can apply the definition of weak and weak-$*$ convergence for element of $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$.

Comment: So, for weak convergence, you need to examine $(f_n(x))$ for a fixed $x\in\ell_q$. (And note you do the same for weak* convergence.)